# Php textfile search

Tags: php

I have a little problem with this code I have here. This code searches in a txt file and returnes what it has found.
Now what I want to do is change the file path with a $_GET method

But when I put in a $_GET method inside the "" it just says alot of errors such as "Your path cannot be empty"

What does not work:

```
$handle = @fopen(."$_GET['filepath']"., "r");
```

How I want it

```
$handle = @fopen("I/want/this/$_get/method", "r");
```

Full code

```
 <?php
    function find_value($input) {
    // $input is the word being supplied by the user
    $handle = @fopen("/users/edwin/list.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
      while (!feof($handle)) {
        $entry_array = explode(":",fgets($handle));
        if ($entry_array[0] == $input) {
          return $entry_array[1];
          }
        }
      fclose($handle);
      }
    return NULL;
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: `$handle = @fopen(."$_GET['filepath']"., "r");` should be `$handle = @fopen($_GET['filepath'], "r");` FYI, **huge security risk**

Comment: This is a **VERY** bad idea, you're opening yourself up to a HUGE security vulnerability in that anyone with half a brain and some computer knowledge can dump the contents of any file on your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you're handling your quotes.

```
$handle = @fopen($_GET['filepath'], "r");
```

Since it's a variable, it does not have to be encapsulated at all, unlike a string.